# Remove Element with multiple Class without ID

Tags: jquery, wijgrid

Been Googling and couldn't find the answer.  How do I go about removing THIS specific div and child after that, without an id (it was generated by WijGrid)

```
<div class="wijmo-wijsuperpanel-vbar-buttontop ui-state-default ui-corner-tr">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span>
</div>
```

I tried, but no go

```
$('.wijmo-wijsuperpanel-vbar-buttontop .ui-state-default .ui-corner-tr').remove();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the spaces in your selector:

```
$('.wijmo-wijsuperpanel-vbar-buttontop.ui-state-default.ui-corner-tr').remove();
```

With the spaces, it would select elements with `ui-corner-tr` class inside an element with `ui-state-default` class inside an element with `wijmo-wijsuperpanel-vbar-buttontop` class.

Comment: Yup that works since Claudio mentioned as well, next question is, if i replace space with ',' (commas), what does that define?

Comment: @sgkdnay That selects elements with any of the three classes you have specified.

Comment: ahh NOW i get the differences between all of em..  Again thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Remove whitespaces, otherwise you're asking for descendents and not elements containing ALL classes.

```
$('.wijmo-wijsuperpanel-vbar-buttontop.ui-state-default.ui-corner-tr').remove();
```