# How to remove class with jquery?

Tags: jquery, show-hide, removeclass

How do I remove the hidden class? In order to show the ribbon?

**Html**

```
<div id="alwaysInStockRibbon" class="ribbon-wrapper-productpage hidden">
```

**Css**

```
.hidden {
    display: none!important;
    visibility: hidden!important;
```

I've tried these below without success.

**Jquery**

```
$(".hidden").remove();
$(".hidden").removeClass();
```

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118847/remove-element-with-multiple-class-without-id

Comment: All is there in the DOC link you provided... https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/  We cannot read it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass classname as argument in removeClass method to remove it in matched set:

> Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

```
 $(".hidden").removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#alwaysInStockRibbon").removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell, which class you want to remove.

```
$(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this : removeClass method takes class name to remove. You can put space separated class name if want to remove multiple classes

```
$('.hidden').removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score -2):

or you can do something like this to show that ribbon:

```
$("#alwaysInStockRibbon").css('display','block');
```